# ASP.NET MVC 3 controller failed to receive a json 2D array

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

Not sure if it is a bug or not. I followed some tutorial to post a Json 2D array to a ASP.NET MVC controller, and it works fine when the first element of the array is not empty, otherwise it fails.

Example: If my json obj is

```
var obj = {
   ItemsArr: [[1, 2],[]]   // first element is an array with a few elements
};
```

The controller will receive the data correctly. However if the first element of the 2D array is an empty array, like:

```
var obj = {
    ItemsArr: [[], [1, 2]]  // first element is an EMPTY array
};
```

the controller will receive a null.

I'm using jquery.json-2.3.min.js to convert objs to json strings. 
The converted strings look fine:

```
{"ItemsArr":[[1,2],[]]}
{"ItemsArr":[[],[1,2]]}
```

The model code:

```
public class Model
{
    public List<string[]> ItemsArr {get;set;}
}

public MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult DoSomething( Model model )
    {  ...
    }
}
```

Have anyone met this problem? Any idea to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

===================================

Edit:

After some research, if I changed the empty array to null, it works.

```
{"ItemsArr":[null,[1,2]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest passing a array of objects and create a class with the Same properties on The server side, asp.net MVC will then automatically convert this array (on the JS end) into a list (or any other IEnumerable) that is a part of the action signature.